# Is it possible to set the difficulty of a block to a certain value on a local network?

Tags: hardhat, difficulty

I was playing around with a pseudo-random function that uses the difficulty as a source of randomness, and it got me wondering, if there's a way to enforce a certain `block.difficulty` value on the local network. For example, with Hardhat, there are special network methods like [`hardhat_setBalance`](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/), but I cannot find anything that would allow setting the block difficulty.

If not with Hardhat, is there perhaps any other way to make a local block get mined with a fixed difficulty value?